# Добавочное обстоятельственное значение

Tags: пунктуация, определения

Помогите, пожалуйста, с разъяснением правила «Обособленные определения».
Часто в разъяснении — что такое добавочное обстоятельственное значение — приводят пример с причинным обст. знач., но эти примеры очевидны. Реже встречаются про уступки, а вот про условия примеры мне найти не удалось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, такое:

*Предоставленные самим себе, дети окажутся в трудном положении*.

— здесь важно не столько определительное значение (какие дети?; ср. без обособления: Предоставленные самим себе дети… ), сколько обстоятельственное — условное (при каком условии окажутся в трудном положении?).

Можно заменить придаточным: *Если будут предоставлены самим себе, дети окажутся в трудном положении*